# Connecting WPML-pages with Wordpress REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wpml

I can create pages in different languages with the wordpress rest-api. These are separate pages and they do not know that they are the translation of each other. So is it possible to connect them with een wordpress rest-api call?